# Drop pandas rows by index name

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I have a dataframe of let say 1000 rows. I want to drop the row store in variable `breakval` and also next 10 rows.

```
breakval=[10,100,500]
for i in breakval:
    df=df.drop(df.index[i:i+10])
```

But after first iteration in which row 10-20 are dropped. I want row 100-110 by index name, not by row number. Because row number is reduced by 10, but row index name remain the same.
I am looking for a way to get index by its name. For example if i do `df.index[12]` it will return me the value, though i dropped it. For this purpose i used `df.loc[22].name`, but it worked for a single value

Comment: One solution can be sorting ```breakval``` decreasingly. So ```breakval = [500, 100, 10]``` and doing the same dropping but 500 first, then 100 and then 10

Comment: thanks, it worked, dont know why and how

Comment: I have written the explanation as an answer. Please check.@Talha Anwar

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One solution can be sorting `breakval` decreasingly. So `breakval = [500, 100, 10]` and doing the same dropping but 500 first, then 100 and then 10.

It will also obviously drop the rows and the indices will be updated. But at first, it will drop from index `500 to 510` so the indices of the laters will be updated, the previous indices are not changed.

Then dropping from `100 to 110` will also change the later indices not the previous indices before `100` and same for `10 to 20`.

Answer (score 0):

You should:

- first collect all index values, for rows to be dropped,
- then remove rows with these indices.

For generality, let's define another variable, stating how many rows
should be dropped, starting from each of your locations:

```
nToDrop = 10
```

or maybe *11* if you want to drop the indicated row (e.g. *5*)
**and** *10* rows following it.

To collect the index values, you can run e.g.:

```
idxToDrop = [item
    for sublist in [df.index[i:i+nToDrop] for i in breakval]
        for item in sublist]
```

Note that `[df.index[i:i+nToDrop] for i in breakval]` is a list comprehension
generating a list of *RangeIndex* objects. Conceptually it can be taken as a list of lists.

The whole above expression can also be presented as:

```
[item
    for sublist in listOfLists
        for item in sublist]
```

It flattens this list (of lists), getting a plain list of index values
for rows to be dropped.

Finally, to get the expected result, run:

```
df.drop(idxToDrop, inplace=True)
```

## Edit

Another, maybe faster solution, is to concatenate *RangeIndex* objects
into a pandasonic *Series*, but as *pd.concat* operates e.g. on *Series*
objects, you must also convert each source *RangeIndex* object into
a *Series*.

So you can generate *idxToDrop* also as:

```
idxToDrop = pd.concat([df.index[i:i+nToDrop].to_series() for i in breakval])
```

and then use it in *df.drop* as above.

Answer (score 0):

```
df['row_index'] = np.arange(df.shape[0])
breakval = [10,100,500]
consequtive_entries_to_remove = 10
for i in breakval:
    for j in range(0, consequtive_entries_to_remove):
        df.drop(df.index[df['row_index'] == i+j], inplace=True)

# Remove column name 'row_index'
df.drop(['row_index'], axis = 1, inplace=True)
```